# When Logging into carbon get Error 403 - Forbidden

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I created a new wildcard certificate *.wso2.com, and  i am running wso2am-4.0.0 on a vm.
Access in https://test.wso2.com:9443/publisher  and https://test.wso2.com:9443/devportal is ok, sucess to sign in.
But when i tried to sign in carbon (https://test.wso2.com:9443/carbon), i got error:
Error 403 - Forbidden. Thanks in advance

Comment: The "403 Forbidden" error will be caused if the user doesn't have enough permissions/scopes to access the relevant portal. 

Did the logged-in user have the required permissions to log in to the carbon management console?

Comment: The logged-in user I used was admin/admin, it was  a super admin , it had enough permissions